# Not Showing Correct Position While Searching in Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview, toast

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  
    SearchView searchView;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList list;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Apple");//0th item
        list.add("Apple");//1st item
        list.add("Banana");//2nd item
        list.add("Banana");//3rd item
        list.add("Pineapple");//4th item
        list.add("Pineapple");//5th item
        list.add("Orange");//6th item
        list.add("Orange");//7th item
        list.add("Mango");//8th item
        list.add("Mango");//9th item
        list.add("Grapes");//10th item
        list.add("Grapes");//11th item
        list.add("Lemon");//12th item
        list.add("Lemon");//13th item
        list.add("Melon");//14th item
        list.add("Watermelon");//15th item
        list.add("Watermelon");//16th item
        list.add("Papaya");//17th item
        list.add("Papaya");//18th item

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if(list.contains(query))
                {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Match found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),newText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
           }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int itemPosition     = position;

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,adapter.getItem(position)+ "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String  itemValue    = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this program I give apple as 0th item and first item,banana as 2&3rd item and so on..
but while searching I want to show papaya as 17th or 18th based on which papaya I click .

without searching it will correctly show the number of fruits location.but while searching it will show if 4 item shown in list view it toast 0,1,2,3 based on clicking.Please help me to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a search for example using 'P', pineapple and papaya will be returned. Initially before search Pineapple is positions 4 and 5 and Papaya is 17th and 18th. But when you search only four results will be returned so Pineapple will be position 0, 1 and Papaya will be position 2 and 3. The position of items changes with the number of items in the list. So the behaviour you are seeing is the expected and correct one.